# Don't explicitly initialize variables to null

Tags: dart

I am trying to figure out how to pass a null argument in the constructor, but I am getting this error:

> Don't explicitly initialize variables to null

```
class Dog {
  final id int;
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Dog({this.id=null, this.name, this.age});
}
```

I don't want to pass an id to the constructor. I want to call the constructor like this:

```
  var dog = Dog(
    name: 'Rex',
    age: 15,
  );
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to set it to NULL?? 
Sounds like it is being set to null by default, so maybe try removing it from the constructor call template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By not explicitly assigning to `null`

```
class Dog {
  final id int;
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Dog({this.id, this.name, this.age});
}
```

Remember, be default value of `id` is set to `null`. So if the consumer doesn't pass a value for `id` it will continue to have `null` and so will `name`

If you want to make any parameter mandatory then you should mark that with `@required`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't set variable the default value will be `null`.